# How can I close the notification tray (if opened) programmatically in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

For my app, I need to close the notification tray (if opened) to show the app on foreground.
Any help are welcome.

I tried with writing some intent calls, but as no experience with that, failed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.